# Which version of Netty does DotNetty 0.6.0 align with?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, netty

As we know that DotNetty is a port of Netty to .net, I searched a lot, but couldn't find out which version of Netty is equal to the DotNetty 0.6.0 (latest DotNetty version).

If it's Netty 5, then there might be some problems, Netty 5 was abandoned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know its netty 4.1.x. Not sure what exact version tho

Comment: Thank you very much. It's good to know it and it's to know it's based on Netty 4.x. I'm still wondering where Azure team gave this information.